# Process very large file in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have to read a very large file (14 GB) need to process it line by line and then need to write that line in a separate file.

My initial plan was to read the whole file with `fs.readFileSync` and then split it with new line and then process one line at a time. But then soon I hit the issue that I cant read the whole file into memory because of v8 limit and on top it even if I could I would hit the limit of ram limit for my machine.

What can be the work around for that?

I can split the file into smaller chunk and process that way?

Or there might be much option to handle such scenario in nodejs.

Comment: https://itnext.io/using-node-js-to-read-really-really-large-files-pt-1-d2057fe76b33

Answer (score 0):

You can read the large file line by line as a stream, without the need to have the whole file in memory, like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('file.txt'),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    console.log(line);
});
```

Code example taken from: [How to read a file line by line in Node.js](https://attacomsian.com/blog/reading-a-file-line-by-line-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the new data streaming solution which is the form of `EventStream`. This is a popular NPM module with over 2 million weekly downloads.

See NPM **Event-Stream**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-stream.

You can read this article aswell: https://itnext.io/using-node-js-to-read-really-really-large-files-pt-1-d2057fe76b33

This also describes how your code snipped should look like. The stream is only tested with a 2.55 GB file but you can still try to implement it.